# Laptop won't poweroff Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: shutdown, 16.04

I recently upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 (did a fresh, new installation) but I am having problems when shutting down.

The first problem I had was that laptop crashed when shutting down - I did some research on that and problem found that was the tlp system was causing problems so I ended up disabling the tlp system completely by editing "/etc/default/tlp" file (changed TLP_ENABLE=1 to TLP_ENABLE=0)... this solved the crash problem... however now my laptop shutsdown but it doesn't poweroff... when you hit "esc" key you can see that the system displays the message "Powering-Off" but it does not power-off the laptop. I have tried changing /etc/default/grub parameter as follow:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"

But it doesn't work either.

By the way, this same laptop (Dell latitude D630) had no problems with Ubuntu 14.04.

Does somebody have any idea on how to resolve this issue?, it is really annoying to have to wait for the system to shutdown and then press the power button for 5 second just to poweroff the machine!

Thanks in advance for the help guys!

Comment: does it behave the same if you issue a shutdown command from the commandline ... `sudo shutdown now`?

Comment: the shutdown button does nothing more than execute either `sudo shutdown 0` or `poweroff` command. so ideally there should not be much of a difference.